# Safely start new worker thread on interval C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a worker thread to do some background work. I want it to run periodically. I don't want more then one instance of this thread executing at the same time. Because i don't want the number of threads to spiral out of control.

I start my threads on a timer like so:

```
intervalTimer = new Timer(millisecondInterval);
        intervalTimer.AutoReset = true;
        intervalTimer.Elapsed += StartThread;
```

...

```
private void StartThread(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunTest));
        workerThread.Start();
    }
```

This does not feel safe to me as i may be starting new threads before the first one has finished executing. What is the safe way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: `This does not feel safe to me` me too. Use some sync mechanism like Monitor, Mutex, AutoResetEvent, ManualResetEvent, Semaphore etc

Comment: @EZI Would you care to explain how to implement any of these sync mechanisms. I'm new to multi-threading and the number of libraries in C# is a bit overwhelming.

Comment: Paperwaste, I am going to sleep. Search for SemaphoreSlim. There are 2 methods you should use Wait/Release.

Comment: You might want to look at TPL and Tasks as an alternative to threads.  Nothing wrong with thread approach as such - but have to deal with synchronization objects.  A Task approach might end up cleaner.  I'll try to post a task solution when I have a mo.